# Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Onboarding'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'

Tags: react-native

Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Onboarding'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or mixed up default import and named import when importing.

My app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; // ahi esta bien
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";


import AuthLoadingScreen from './src/screens'

import {Onboarding} from "./src/screens"

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value => {
      if (value == null) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true');
        setIsFirstLaunch(true);
      } else {
        setIsFirstLaunch(false);
      }
      }); 
    }, []);

    if ( isFirstLaunch == null ) {
      return null;
    } else if ( isFirstLaunch == true ) {
      return ( 
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
            <Stack.Screen name="AuthLoadingScreen" component={AuthLoadingScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    } else {
      //return <Login />;
      return ( 
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}

          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
            <Stack.Screen name="AuthLoadingScreen" component={AuthLoadingScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
  }

export default App;
```

and my onboarding.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import Onboarding from 'react-native-onboarding-swiper';


const Dots = ({selected}) => { // Puntos de las paginas del Onboarding
    let backgroundColor;

    backgroundColor = selected ? 'rgba( 40, 109, 213, .8)' : 'rgba(40, 109, 213, .3)';

    return (
        <View 
            style={{
                width:7,
                height: 7,
                marginHorizontal: 3,
                backgroundColor,
                borderRadius: 5,
                
            }}
        />
    );
}

const Skip = ({...props}) => ( // Skip button
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={{marginHorizontal:10}}
        {...props}
    >
        <Text style={{fontSize:16, color: "#286DD5", fontWeight:"900", marginLeft:15, marginRight:15 }}>Skip</Text> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Next = ({...props}) => ( // Next button
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={{marginHorizontal:10}}
        {...props}
    >
        <Text style={{fontSize:16, color: "#286DD5",fontWeight:"900", marginLeft:15, marginRight:15}}>Next</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Done = ({...props}) => ( // Done button
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={{marginHorizontal:10}}
        {...props}
    >
        <Text style={{fontSize:16, color: "#286DD5",fontWeight:"900", marginLeft:15, marginRight:15}}>Done</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const OnboardingScreen = ({navigation}) => {  // Screen Principal del Onboarding
    return (
        <Onboarding
        SkipButtonComponent={Skip}
        NextButtonComponent={Next}
        DoneButtonComponent={Done}
        DotComponent={Dots}
        bottomBarHeight={100}
        bottomBarColor={"#FFF"}

        onSkip={() => navigation.replace("StartScreen")} // Redirigir a la pantalla de Login
        onDone={() => navigation.navigate("StartScreen")} // Redirigir a la pantalla de Login
        pages={[
          {
            backgroundColor: "#FFF",
            image: <Image source={require('../assets/maths.png')} style={styles.images} />, // falta poner la imagen del onboarding
            title: 'Conecta con otros',
            subtitle: 'Una nueva forma de aprender',
          },
          {
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',

            image: <Image source={require('../assets/colab.png')} style={styles.images2} />, // falta poner la imagen del onboarding
            title: 'Se parte de una nueva comunidad',
            subtitle: 'Un nuevo espacio para ayudar y ser ayudado',
          },
          {
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            image: <Image source={require('../assets/problem.png')} style={styles.images3} />, // falta poner la imagen del onboarding
            title: 'Resuelve tus problemas',
            subtitle: 'Aqui los problemas se transforman en conocimiento',
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
};

export default OnboardingScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ // Estilos de la Screen
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  images: { 
    width: 220,
    height: 230,
  },
  images2: { 
    width: 260,
    height: 210,
  },
  images3: { 
    width: 270,
    height: 200,
  },
});
```